# DJango Ajax - Like button only changes in first post when clicked

Tags: jquery, django, ajax

I am am working on a website where users can like posts and in which I have lists of all user posts on the homepage.

I am using Ajax to prevent the page from reloading when a like button is clicked. I was able to implement a like view, but I have an issue. Ajax is working properly, but only the like button in the first post changes when clicked, from Like to Unlike. The Like button in the second post does not change.

My code is as follows:

```
@login_required
def home_view(request):
    #All posts in new feed
    all_images = Post.objects.filter(
        Q(poster_profile=request.user, active=True)|
        Q(poster_profile__from_user__to_user=request.user, active=True)|
        Q(poster_profile__to_user__from_user=request.user, active=True)|
        Q(poster_profile__profile__friends__user=request.user, active=True))

    #If post is liked displayed button
    posts = Post.objects.filter(pk__in=all_images)
    is_liked = {}
    for post in posts:
        if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
            is_liked[post.id] = True

   context = {'all_images': all_images, 'is_liked': is_liked}
   return render(request,'home.html', context)

   #Post likes
   @login_required
   def like_post_view(request):
       # post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('post_id'))
       post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('id'))
       is_liked = False
       if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
           post.likes.remove(request.user)
           is_liked = False
       else:
           is_liked = True
           post.likes.add(request.user)
       context = {'post': post, 'is_liked': is_liked,}
       if request.is_ajax():
           html = render_to_string('ajax_postlikes.html', context, request=request)
       return JsonResponse({'form': html})
       return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

Template: ajax_postlike.html

```
    <p>Like{{post.likes.count}}</p>

    <form action="{% url 'site:like_post' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% if is_liked %}
    <button type="submit" name="post_id" value="{{ post.id }}" class="like float-left mr-2">
    Unlike
    </button>
    {% else %}
    <button type="submit" name="post_id" value="{{ post.id }}" class="like float-left mr-2">
    like
    </button>
    {% endif %}
    </form>
```

Template: home.html

```
    <div class="ml-1" id="like-section">
    {% include 'ajax_postlikes.html' %}
    </div>
```

Ajax/Jquery:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', '.like', function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      var pk = $(this).attr('value');
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "{% url 'site:like_post' %}",
        data: {'id':pk, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
          $('#like-section{{ post.id }}').html(response['form'])
          console.log($('#like-section{{ post.id }}').html(response['form']));
      },
      error: function(rs, e) {
      console.log(rs.resopnseText);
    },
   });
  });
 </script>
```

What do I need to do to fix my issue with the button state not toggling between "like" and "unlike", after a click event?

[![enter image description here][1]][1][1]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4MWc.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The home.html template has 'like-section' as an ID, yet your JQuery selector gets $('#like-section{{ post.id }}') - the lack of post.id in the template might be why only the first post is being updated.

```html
<div class="ml-1" id="like-section">
    {% include 'ajax_postlikes.html' %}
</div>
```

**Edit:**
So I've recreated your views, models, etc. and managed to get it to work with some changes.

1. I've changed the home.html template to include a Django template language for loop, I couldn't see this in your original code so not sure how the posts are being created in the template exactly. This format will work when loading the page and when making the AJAX call for a single like. I've also made some changes to the AJAX call and how the response is handled, I noticed some stray template language which won't work.

```html
  <body>
    <div class="ml-1" id="like-section">
      {% for post in post_list %}
        {% include 'ajax_postlikes.html' %}
      {% endfor %}
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).on('click', '.like', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var pk = $(this).attr('value');

        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: "{% url 'like_post_view' %}",
          headers: { 'X-CSRFToken': $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val() },
          data: {id: pk},
          success: function(response) {
            $('#like-section'+pk).html(response)
          },
          error: function(rs, e) {
            console.log(rs.responseText);
          },
         });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
```

2. I've also change the ajax_postlikes.html format, I think you've already done this, but I added an ID to the form. I have also change how the if/else statement works which is explained in the view.

```html
<form id='like-section{{ post.id }}' action="{% url 'like_post_view' %}" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
{% if post.liked_by_user %}
<button type="submit" name="post_id" value="{{ post.id }}" class="like float-left mr-2">
Unlike
</button>
{% else %}
<button type="submit" name="post_id" value="{{ post.id }}" class="like float-left mr-2">
Like
</button>
{% endif %}
</form>
```

3. This is the home view in views.py - instead of having a variable for is_liked and separating the two, you can add a variable to the QuerySet object which can then be referenced in the template (shown above).

```py
def home_view(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()

    for post in posts:
        print(post)
        print(post.likes.filter(user=request.user).exists())
        if post.likes.filter(user=request.user).exists():
            post.liked_by_user = True
        else:
            post.liked_by_user = False

    context = {'post_list': posts}
    return render(request, 'home.html' , context)
```

4. Lastly, I've updated the AJAX view along the same lines.

```py
def like_post_view(request):
   post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('id'))

   if post.likes.filter(user=request.user).exists():
       Like.objects.filter(post=post,user=request.user).delete()
       post.liked_by_user = False
   else:
       Like.objects.create(post=post, user=request.user)
       post.liked_by_user = True

   context = {'post': post}

   if request.is_ajax():
       return render(request, 'ajax_postlike.html', context)

   return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

This is working for me and updates the button (i.e. the form) when each are clicked. I realise that I've removed some of your filtering and other model logic but that should be easy to add back in.

Comment: @OsVoid...same error. Only the first like button toggle.

Comment: @OsVoid...if I use class="like-section" and also class="like". When I click like button on first post, the like button of second post toggle with the button of the first post. But only the first post liked is saved in database, how do I implement like button only toggle for the particular post button I clicked. Do you think this could be the template problem?

Comment: If the ID change didn't fix it then it might be something in the view. Does it work correctly when the page is first loaded, so ignoring the AJAX call?

Comment: @OsVoid...yes it worked correctly without Ajax, when i implemented Ajax with my code this error comes up

Comment: It doesn't look like anything wrong with the template so must be in the view - I would log the post, is_liked, context and the response on the front-end and make sure it all goes through as expected with the right IDs

Comment: @OsVoid.. What do you mean, I don't understand.

Comment: In like_post_view put print(context) before the returns and you’ll see the context in the terminal, check that and the other variables to see at which point it’s going wrong

Comment: @OsVoid... When I print out context, I get the right post I liked in console. And also the post id, but the like button still toggle for both post

Comment: I've updated my response with another suggestion, I've managed to get it working so hopefully this works for you

Comment: @OsVoid.. Thanks, in your post_like_view. Like is not a class Model. This is it; class Post(models.Model): likes = models.ManyToManyField('Profile', related_name='post_likes')

Comment: Ah no problem, then just change the `Like.objects.create` with `post.likes.add(request.user.profile)` - I think you originally used `request.user`

Comment: @OsVoid... Thanks, you save my day. But a problem occurred, when like button is clicked, it doesn't display the unlike button, it just show empty unless I refresh my page the unlike button is shown. And also comment count is not updating as well.

Comment: @OsVoid... Thanks, you save my day. But a problem occurred, when like button is clicked, it doesn't display the unlike button, it just show empty unless I refresh my page the unlike button is shown. And also comment count is not updating as well.

Comment: @OsVoid.. I update my question including like count in ajax_likes_post template

Comment: If the unlike button isn't showing then it's probably something wrong with how JQuery is updating the HTML, that part did work in my version. Including `post.likes.count` means you'll need to change the structure slightly as your JQuery is replacing the form but the count sits outside of this

Comment: @OsVoid.. Okay I have done that, by including form in ajax. You can correct your answer.  $('#like-section' +pk).html(response['form'])

Comment: @OsVoid... I will make another question and send you the link, it's about comment in ajax. I was able to implement comment with Ajax, but in home page when I submit a form, the comment doesn't show, it disappeared.

Comment: @OsVoid... I got duplicate on like count. It displayed twice when like is clicked. I attached an image to my question, you can see for your self.

Comment: Check your JQuery, looks like you're appending it to the div without doing anything to the existing value

Comment: @OsVoid.. I'm using the jquery in your answer as you suggested, and I tried {% if post.likes.all %}<p>Like{{post.likes.count}}</p>{% endif %} it always duplicate like count

Comment: Make sure you're replacing the entire div in the AJAX success function, including the `<p>` tags, otherwise you'll keep adding more. I think you've just replaced the form previously so your AJAX will replace the form with the form _and_ p tags (and so on and so forth)

Comment: @OsVoid... I'm confused about your example, can you update your answer?

Comment: @OsVoid.. I don't know if it is a better approach adding the like count in like and unlike button, but it worked as I want it. <button type="submit" name="post_id" value="{{ post.id }}" class="like float-left mr-2">
Unlike  {{ post.like_count }}
</button>